# Getting Exception: "Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint"

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

In my storyboard application I try to add extra `UITextField` to interface. But I get the exception that title says. I use [SwiftAutoLayout](https://github.com/indragiek/SwiftAutoLayout) library. Here is my code:

```
// MARK: - IBOutlets

@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

// MARK: - Properties

let userIdTextField = UITextField()

// MARK: - Lifecycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.passwordTextField.keyboardType = .NumberPad

    if getCurrentUserId() == nil {
        self.view.addSubview(userIdTextField)
        userIdTextField.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        self.view.addConstraints([userIdTextField.al_leading == passwordTextField.al_leading,
            userIdTextField.al_trailing == passwordTextField.al_trailing,
            userIdTextField.al_top == passwordTextField.al_bottom + 8])
        userIdTextField.placeholder = "Enter User Id..."
    }
}
```

Comment: Must add the item to it's parent view first

Comment: In xcode 10 beta 5 release notes: The exception “Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.” has improved diagnostics. (42514606)

Answer (score 87):

Try adding  `passwordTextField` to its superview before binding any constraints to it.

---

**UPD** (thanks @vmeyer and @MacMark): please notice that it's safer to add constraints not in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear` but in  [updateViewConstraints](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621379-updateviewconstraints) or [viewWillLayoutSubviews](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621437-viewwilllayoutsubviews) since the view hierarchy might be unprepared for this operation.

Comment: I had a similar crash but the view was created within the code. And indeed I was add constraints before adding the view. If your view is already in the storyboard, could you add the constraints directly there?

Answer (score 12):

I suggest you to not add constraints in viewDidLoad, because the view hierarchy is set, but not constraints.
You should prefer [updateViewConstraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/updateViewConstraints) or [viewWillLayoutSubviews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews)

Comment: This answer is good since adding constraints in didLoad or will/DidAppear can crash the app due to view hierarchy unprepared for this.

Answer (score 5):

Please add the view to superview before adding constraints for the view in superview.

`superView?.addSubview(view)
superView?.addConstraints([topConstraint,leftConstraint,bottomConstraint,rightConstraint])`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to adding constraint to view which is not added/created in current view hierarchy. First add view then apply constraint.