# Swift add constraint programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I add a `UILabel` (amountLabel) in `UIViewController` in storyboard editor. And then in swift file, `viewDidLoad`, I programatically create a `UITextField` (paymentTextField) and try to add a constraint between `amountLabel` and `paymentTextField`. Here is my code in `viewDidload`:

```
let paymentTextField = UITextField()
    paymentTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    paymentTextField.frame = CGRectMake(15, 100, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) - 30, 44)
    self.view.addSubview(paymentTextField)

    let bottonConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: paymentTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.amountLabel , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 30)
    bottonConstraint.identifier = "paymentTextFieldSpacing"
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([bottonConstraint])
```

But I get an error:

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with items > and > because they have no common ancestor. 
>   Does the constraint reference items in different view hierarchies? 
>   That's illegal."

Does anyone know what is wrong? `amountLabel` is directly dragged to the view in storyboard and "paymentTextField" is added programmatically to the same view. Why have they no common ancestor?

Answer (score 151):

I ran into the same problem that you described earlier. In order to make the programmatic subview, (in your case the paymentTextField) you have to add this to the subview first and then apply your constraints.

By adding the subview to view first, this ensures both views have the same parent.

Comment: I can verify this. It happened to me when I tried to activate constraints but forgot to add the subviews to the super view.

Comment: Good help! Thanks

Answer (score 23):

Checklist for this ISSUE:

- Check whether you added the programmatically created view to its parent **before activating constraints**
- Check whether you write constraints activation code inside **viewDidLoad() / viewWillAppear()**. You should write constraints activation code in  **updateViewConstraints or viewWillLayoutSubviews**. ( [suggested by vmeyer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35266103/2666902) )
- Check whether you turn off **translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints**.

Answer (score 12):

The error states that "because they have no common ancestor", which means that they don't share the same parent. In order to relate constraint between two items, they have to have a child-parent relationship or a sibling one.

In your case just make sure they have the same parent view before adding the constraint programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I couldn't figure out how to give amountLabel and paymentTextField the same parent. I dragged amountLabel in storyboard and its parent should be the outer view. I added paymentTextField programmatically to self.view and its parent should also be the outer view. How come they have different parent?

Comment: Have you confirmed they do have same parent, like printing paymentTextField.superview? If they don't, just drag an IBOutlet from the storyboard outerview to the controller and use it to add paymentTextField as a subview. 

Also, make sure you are adding the constraint AFTER the addSubview call, not before.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you added the `paymentTextField` to your view:

```
paymentTextField.translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(paymentTextField)

...
```

Add your constraints, for example `paymentTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true`

Answer (score 1):

```
let nameLabel: UILabel = {

   let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()
```

if you forgot setting this `label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`
        or if you add subview after constraints 
this problem  arises

Comment: you should add constrints after adding the subview

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 4 & 5**

```
final class VoiceSearchViewController: UIViewController {
   // MARK: - Properties
   var backgroundView: UIView = {
     let view = UIView()
     view.layer.cornerRadius = 20
     view.backgroundColor = .red
     return view
   }()

  // MARK: - Life Cycle Methods
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initialSetup()
  }

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  // MARK: - Private Methods
  private func initialSetup() {
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
    view.addSubview(backgroundView)
    backgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    backgroundView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    backgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    backgroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    backgroundView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
  }
}
```