# Custom UICollectionViewLayout Drawing Line One Certain Cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a custom UICollectionViewLayout and I wanna draw a line over certain cell like in the image below:

[image] 
When I draw a line on collectionview, the line is lapping over the header cells which is something I do not want. Can you please suggest me what should I do?

Comment: How are you drawing the line? Is it a separate `UIView`?

Comment: Yes, I add UIView currently.

Comment: Can you post your relevant code? You should be able to constrain your view to the top of the collection view, offset by the height of the header.

Comment: Offsetting :) that is something I have not tought off. I got your point many thanks, I will try now!!

Comment: Did offsetting the view work for you?

Comment: not really. I am trying to add constraints but getting this error: 
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.'

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26349234/6658553 If you are still running into issues, edit your question with your current code so myself or others will be more able to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160315/discussion-between-val-nolav-and-nathan).